# Merging two numbers in python without list

Tags: python, numbers

I need to merge two numbers and create all possible outcomes.

Lets say we have `a = 45` and `b = 766`, we are looking for such numbers `**45**766`, `**4**7**5**66`, `**4**76**5**6` and so on, In a way that the original numbers stay in the same order (we can't do `**54**766`).

I can use only math to solve this.
Can you name any method or path of thinking to achieve this goal?

Comment: Convert `a` and `b` to string. Concatenate the string. Apply some logic to generate those permutations. Then convert the string result back to int.

Comment: I cannot do that, only mathematics, no strings no lists.

Comment: Then combine `a` and `b` using multiplication, division and modulo operators. `45 * 1000 + 766 = 45766`. `45 modulo 10 = 5, 45 / 10 = 4, 4 * 10000 + 766 * 10 + 5 = 47665`. Something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a recursive generator function that does this. There are two recursive cases, one where you take one digit from `a` and one where you take a digit from `b`.

```
def merge(a, b):
    if a == 0:                 # base cases
        yield b
        return
    if b == 0:
        yield a
        return
    
    digit = a % 10             # recursive case where we take last digit from `a`
    for x in merge(a//10, b):  # the recursive call omits that last digit
        yield x*10 + digit     # put the digit to the right of the recursive results

    digit = b % 10             # do all the same things for a digit from `b`
    for x in merge(a, b//10):
        yield x*10 + digit
```

You can call it like this:

```
>>> print(list(merge(45, 766)))
[76645, 76465, 74665, 47665, 76456, 74656, 47656, 74566, 47566, 45766]
```